# О внутрисловных разделителях

Tags: лексика, словообразование, тире, дефис, апостроф

По моим наблюдениям, в русском языке есть три внутрисловных разделителя, а именно:

1. дефис (примеры употребления дефиса: по**-**русски, мать**-**и**-**мачеха),
2. знак "ъ" (примеры употребления "ъ": под**ъ**язок, кон**ъ**юнкция, диз**ъ**юнкция),
3. знак "ь" (пример употребления "ь" в качестве разделителя: руж**ь**ё).

**Вопрос:** Сколько нужно иметь внутрисловных разделителей в русском языке?

P.S.: Во вводном слове "в частности" пробел используется в качестве внутрисловного разделителя.

Answer (score 4):

К вышеназванным я б ещё добавил пробел (предлог и существительное фонетически являются одним словом, но пишутся через пробел), тире (*водитель - старший инструктор*) и разделительные гласные "о", "е" (пар**о**ход и кон**е**завод). Условно можно ещё добавить непроизносимые сочетания звуков, во всяком случае слышать произношение типа *со-нцэ*,мне доводилось. Итого: шесть-семь, хотя мог и забыть что-нибудь.

Пожалуй, остальные "внутрисловные" делители, включая апостроф, были бы излишними.

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: Ближайшая к нам звезда обозначается и словом "солнце" (в русском языке), и словом "сонце" (в украинском языке).